# How do I Pivot in Oracle query when the value is a comma separated string?

Tags: oracle

I have rows in a database as follows with a value being a comma separated string of numbers...

```
starttime   endtime   parametername   parametervalue
---------   -------   -------------   --------------
2:00pm      2:15pm    thisparameter   0,0,111,222,333
```

The desired result is...

```
starttime   endtime  thisparameter
---------   -------  -------------
2:00pm      2:15pm   0,0,111,222,333
```

If this was a number, I could just do a PIVOT on the sum, but that of course doesn't work, because it cannot aggregate the comma separated field.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you just poorly format the question? Because, desired result looks exactly like what you already have (witout the PARAMETERNAME column). Or do you not understand the question?

Comment: No, I want the value in column 3 to become the column header, and the matching value in column 4 to be in column 3.  column 3 is the corresponding name to column 4's value.

Answer (score 1):

You can still summarize the comma separated numbers using `PIVOT` if you split the comma separated numbers into multiple rows.

The query below splits the comma separated numbers into multiple rows, then summarizes them with `PIVOT`

NOTE: The query below will not work for numbers that have a decimal point. If your numbers do have decimals, you will need to adjust the regex that is splitting the rows.

```sql
WITH
    d
    AS
        (SELECT '2:00pm'              AS starttime,
                '2:15pm'              AS endtime,
                'thisparameter'       AS parametername,
                '0,0,111,222,333'     AS parametervalue
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '3:00pm'            AS starttime,
                '3:15pm'            AS endtime,
                'thisparameter'     AS parametername,
                '55,66'             AS parametervalue
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT starttime, endtime, thisparameter
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM d
               CROSS APPLY (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (parametervalue,
                                                      '\d+',
                                                      1,
                                                      LEVEL)    AS split_num
                                  FROM DUAL
                            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (parametervalue, '\d+')))
       PIVOT (SUM (split_num) FOR parametername IN ('thisparameter' AS thisparameter));


   STARTTIME    ENDTIME    THISPARAMETER
____________ __________ ________________
2:00pm       2:15pm                  666
3:00pm       3:15pm                  121
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LISTAGG` to aggregate within the `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT( 
  LISTAGG( parametervalue ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY parametervalue )
  FOR parametername IN (
    'thisparameter' AS thisparameter
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( starttime, endtime, parametername, parametervalue ) AS
SELECT '2:00pm', '2:15pm', 'thisparameter', '0,0,111,222,333' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> STARTTIME | ENDTIME | THISPARAMETER  
> :-------- | :------ | :--------------
> 2:00pm    | 2:15pm  | 0,0,111,222,333
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d1228eca896d2bf4e9cb3232ee5a6876)*